# Parse a multi dimentional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, excel

I have an array

```
[1] => Array (
[1] => Report
)
[2] => Array (
[1] => Merchant Name
[2] => Merchant Id
[3] => Merchant Ref No
[4] => Trans Date
[5] =>  Ref No
[6] => Trans Type
[7] => Trans Amt
[8] => Trans Fee
[9] => Serv Tax
[10] => Total Fee
[11] => Amt Settled
[12] => Neft Ref.No
[13] => Settlmnt Date
[14] => Funds Settld Date
)
[3] => Array (
[1] => yy Private Limited
[2] => ESSIZMM000
[3] => zWidItN33452373TcH
[4] => 2014-12-02 10:27:47.82
[5] => 265135490490229682
[6] => SALES
[7] => 249
[8] => 2.241
[9] => 0.277
[10] => 2.518
[11] => 246.482
[12] => ABB SL : 00012
[13] => 04-12-2014
[14] => 04-12-2014
)
```

This is an array I got after parsing an excel.The first array is the header of the excel where the column names are there and the second array onwards is the real data comes.Can some one help me how to parse out all the 11th index of the array except the first array?Here the 11th index is an amount , but in the first array ,is the header 'Amt Settled' which I don't need.

I tried this

```
$cells = $worksheet['cells'];

foreach ($cells as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value['11'];
}
```

where $cells is the array which is printed above.But when I'm using this i'm getting

```
Amt Settled246.482
```

How can I skip that first array ,ie the header of the excel.Is there some better suggestion for this other than my code?Please help

Comment: Depends on what you're using to read the Excel file, and even whether it's a real Excel file or simply a CSV file; but basically you should do it in your code where you implement the logic of what you actually want

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks.The final array im getting after parsing is this.I wanted a help in the logic

Comment: You want to remove this also : `[1] => Array (
[1] => Report
)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($cells as $key => $value)
{
    if ($i > 2) {
        echo $value['11'];
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
$your_array = your array goes here;
array_shift($your_array);
print_r($your_array);

//here you do your foreach

?>
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

Edit: I think in your case you have to use array_shift 2 times to remove this also : `[1] => Array ( [1] => Report )`

If so try this :

```
<?php
$your_array = your array goes here;
array_shift($your_array);
array_shift($your_array);
print_r($your_array);

//here you do your foreach

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the cell data starts at ['cells'][3] you can [slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) the array from index 3 down:

```
$cells = array_slice($worksheet['cells'], 3, NULL, TRUE);

foreach ($cells as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value['11'];
}
```